# Debugging jquery post

Tags: jquery, vb.net

We are having a issue with a function called GetNotes its throwing a 500 error and not much else info is their a better way to. Debug  the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //get the string from the textbox
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/dynamic/CustomerHomePage.aspx/GetNoteTable",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (date) {

                    Success(date);
                },
                error: Failed
            });
```

This is the function obv dont want to show it all as company info which is in the code behind file.

```
<WebMethod()> _
 <ScriptMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function GetNoteTable() As String
 End Function
```

Its just finding it hard to debug I am using inspect element console.
[image]

Comment: _"is their a better way to debug the code"_ Can you attach an actual debugger to your webserver?

Comment: I going bring it down locally and do just that but In Visual studio how does one debug jquery its not usually the best.

Comment: Well you've got two errors going on there.  The unexpected token is some bad syntax in a client side JS file.  The 500 error is coming back from the server side VB code.  The first you can debug in your browser, the second you debug with VS.

Comment: @JamesThorpe but the brower only shows me the token not what it is

Comment: @JamesThorpe it was a nasty null affecting a user so that what caused the issue of the web service failing so we put new appropriate null check in to avoid the issue in future